# Who owns MemoryStream objects placed on the clipboard? (Or should something other than MemoryStream be used?)

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard, memorystream

I have a method like this:

```
public DataObject GetClipboardData()
{
    var result = new DataObject();
    result.SetText(this.fallbackText.ToString());
    result.SetData(DataFormats.Html, this.GenerateHtml(), false);
    return result;
}
```

where `GenerateHtml` returns a `MemoryStream`.

Do I need to be worried about closing the `MemoryStream` object? Or should I use some other type of object to place raw bytes on the clipboard?

(I tried `byte[]` but this places the text `"System.Byte[]"` or similar on the clipboard)

Comment: You could put it on the clipboard as a Base64String and then you wouldn't need to worry about the lifetime of the MemoryStream.

Comment: @Kevin: Base64 would not comply with the `DataFormats.Html` standard. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917.aspx )

Comment: I think in theory you should worry about, but in practice not, as Clipboard will create a copy of the pointer to the same MemoryStream data, but after this it's lifetime depends on other applications present in OS. So even if you by calling Dispose() can destroy it, it would not be correct from the behavior point of view.

Comment: You need not dispose a Memorystream: it is a glorified byte[]. If you're worried about memory leaks, post half a gigabyte to see if it gets cleaned properly.

Comment: @jdv: Is that documented anywhere? I can't find anything in `MemoryStream`'s contract which says it is okay not to close it.

Comment: It follows from first principles, the GC manages memory, you only need IDisposable to release other resources early.  MemoryStream just uses memory, its Dispose() method doesn't call GC.Collect().  Very, very hard to convince .NET programmers about that, it's there so must be called.  The .NET object model doesn't allow un-inheriting a method, can't get rid of the Stream.Dispose() methods.  Actually calling it has crashed many programs that use MemoryStream to copy an Image and avoid the file lock.  MemoryStream sets the CanRead property to false.  Kaboom!  Later, very hard to diagnose.

Comment: @Hans: It isn't clear from `MemoryStream`'s contract that the buffer it uses is on the managed heap. The GC only manages memory it knows about.

Comment: MemoryStream source code is public: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx In most cases MemoryStream's Dispose method is a no-op unless you use certain async methods.

Comment: @Palo: Just because the current implementation works that way does not require future implementations to act that way. e.g. note how `StringBuilder` is a completely different data structure in .NET 2 vs .NET 4.

Comment: In `Windows.Forms`, there is a `Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true)` overload which specifically copies such streams rather than just referencing them, meaning you can dispose them after that call. Doesn't WPF have that too?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if an object implements `IDisposable` is a good thing to dispose it when you don't need it anymore.

`DataObject` provides a basic implementation of the `IDataObject` interface so why don't you derive from it:

```
public sealed class HtmlDataObject : DataObject, IDisposable
{
    protected MemoryStream HtmlMemoryStream { get; set; }

    public HtmlDataObject(MemoryStream memoryStream, string fallBackText)
    {
        HtmlMemoryStream = memoryStream;
        SetText(fallBackText);
        SetData(DataFormats.Html, false, HtmlMemoryStream );
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        HtmlMemoryStream .Dispose();
    }
}
```

So your method can be changed:

```
public HtmlDataObject GetClipboardData()
{
    return new HtmlDataObject(this.GenerateHtml(), this.fallbackText.ToString());
}
```

And you can put it into an `using statement` or `Dispose()` it when you have finished using it.

**Final thought:** You should not worry about clipboard data because the `DataObject` will be destroyed anyway when you exit the application and your clipboard will lose what you put inside with it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278673.aspx

If you want that the stream is persisted after disposing it and/or when the application exit you have to use [Clipboard.SetDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the `copy` parameter = `true`

Comment: This just moves the problem into `Clipboard.SetData` :)

Comment: @BillyONeal I don't agree because when you dispose HtmlDataObject the memorystream is disposed. Object are passed by reference.

Comment: How do you know whether or not to destroy HtmlDataObject? It got passed to the clipboard. Does the clipboard make a copy or does it merely reference the existing object?

Comment: @BillyONeal Anyway it is going to be destroyed when you exit from your application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278673.aspx